# How to list all services that start AFTER certain service in systemd

Tags: systemd

I would like to find in this way (if possible) which services wait for *NetworkManager-wait-online.service* to execute before they start?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the command you are looking for is:

```
$ systemctl list-dependencies --reverse NetworkManager-wait-online.service 
NetworkManager-wait-online.service
● └─network-online.target
●   └─hddtemp.service
```

From `man systemctl`:

```
   list-dependencies [NAME]
       Shows units required and wanted by the specified unit. This
       recursively lists units following the Requires=, Requisite=,
       ConsistsOf=, Wants=, BindsTo= dependencies. If no unit is
       specified, default.target is implied.

       By default, only target units are recursively expanded. When --all
       is passed, all other units are recursively expanded as well.

       Options --reverse, --after, --before may be used to change what
       types of dependencies are shown.

   --reverse
       Show reverse dependencies between units with list-dependencies,
       i.e. follow dependencies of type WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, PartOf=,
       BoundBy=, instead of Wants= and similar.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure. It is a very short list... When I put --after instead, it becomes a very long list. I have disabled the service, as it was causing a long boot delay, and now I'm trying to see which service might suffer from this decision.

Comment: Note that `--after` shows all other units that specified to start the mentioned one after themselves. You are either looking for `--reverse` or maybe `--before`, which shows all units before which the mentioned one needs to be started.

Comment: Yes, --before could be it. It's good to see that services which should be started after that service are still started somehow even when it is disabled. Thanks! :)