# Erase /home/<user> from casper-rw overlay on shutdown (systemd service)

Tags: mount, shutdown, systemd, home-directory

In my company we use a USB bootable live stick with Ubuntu (erm... Xubuntu) 18.04 to do job interviews. It has a bunch of tools (three or four IDEs, a couple of database GUI viewers...) and a toy project to ask questions about.

That USB stick has a Casper-RW overlay partition for persistent storage (created with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)). Said partition is mostly used to store Docker images and to keep some start-up values that can change a bit depending on which machine the stick is plugged into.

That partition is mounted *"manually"* in `/media/overlay` by adding the following line `mkdir --parents /media/overlay/ && mount -L casper-rw /media/overlay/`
 to the file `rc.local` (thank you [@sudodus](https://askubuntu.com/users/55537/sudodus) for [answering my previous question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1153621/270451)).

Now, that `casper-rw` persistence layer is working great... Maybe too great. We would like to erase the `/home/<user>` directory where the `.bash_history` and other changes made by the interviewee have been stored when we shut down the test environment (test environment... meaning: the laptop where the interviewee has been doing stuff) so it's ready for the next candidate.

Thanks to these answers ([Unix&Linux](https://superuser.com/a/1016848/129200), [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/779653/270451)) I created a systemd service that... kindaaaa does what I want, it's just it seems to do it when the system ***boots***, not when it's going down. Is not a huge deal, is just... it bugs me a little **:-D**

This is the systemd service I created in `/etc/systemd/system/clear-stick.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Cleans-up interview sticker
RequiresMountsFor=/media/overlay/
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target umount.target casper.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/clear_interview_stick.sh
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/clear_interview_stick.sh
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I suspect it's only running the `ExecStart` line on boot, rather than the `ExecStop` line on shutdown. If I make changes to the `/home/` directory, power off the computer and mount the stick somewhere else, the changes are still there. Plus, if I look at the logs in `journalctl` I only see references to *Cleans-up interview sticker* surrounded by what seem start sequences of other services.

I'm not 100% sure whether this happens because the `.service` definition is wrong (very likely) or because I don't fully understand how the `casper-rw` overlay works and even though the `.service` is run on shutdown, it can't clear the `/media/overlay/home/interviewee` directory?.

As I mentioned before, it's not a huge, *huge* deal, since it seems to be erasing the `/home/` directory on boot, but I'd rather do it *"""right"""* and erase it on shutdown.

And just in case it's relevant, this is the content of `/usr/local/bin/clear_interview_stick.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

had_to_mount="false";
if [[ ! -d "/media/overlay/upper/" ]]; then
    mount -L casper-rw /media/overlay/
    had_to_mount="true";
fi

if [[ -d "/media/overlay/upper/home/interviewee/" ]]; then
    echo "Removing interviewee /home";
    rm -rf "/media/overlay/upper/home/interviewee/";
else
    echo "interviewee /home/ not found"
fi

if [[ -f /root/.bash_history ]]; then
    rm /root/.bash_history;
fi

if [[ "${had_to_mount}" == "true" ]]; then
       umount /media/overlay;
fi
```

Comment: are you sure your casper is not unmounted before `Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target umount.target casper.service`. Could you try if using `After=final.target`  instead makes a difference? That one is called BEFORE unmounting takes place but before shutdown cs.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure of anything at all @Rinzwind (thank you for the hint, btw!!) I know nothing about systemd. I will try and let you know. **:-)** It probably is unmounted, though. That'd explain why I had to add the `mount` to the `bash` script.

Comment: ahhhhh yes stupid me thinking wtf do you need a conditional mount there :D That is likely the issue. You are too late with your service :) You could also do it after network.target if not before final.target. If so: make it an answer yourself and accept it ;)

Comment: Gonna try `After=network.target` (and no `Before`) But if it works, you sould make the answer and I'll gladly choose it. I mean... you have reputation to spare, but what's right is right **:D**

Comment: I can put more rep into a bounty than you have so go for it ;-) Ill upvote it

Comment: So, I tried doing the `After=network.target`, removing all the `Before`(s) and making `ExecStart=/bin/true`. That didn't seem to work. Maybe I shouldn't have changed the `ExecStart`?? (that's what I get for getting creative!!) I'm gonna try substituting the `After=network...` by `Before=final.target`. I'll keep you posted (and again: that you so much for all these hints!!)

Comment: It's done. It's alive. It's aliiiiive **:D**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY!! I got it!!!. Thank you so much to [@Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind) who gave me crucial clues in the comments to the question for this.

> (**!!**) If someone is reading these words, please: don't assume this is ***the*** *right* way of doing it because it probably isn't. I am really new to SystemD and I know mostly... well... absolutely nothing about it.

I got it working using a service that *Exec**Starts*** (important, I had been trying a lot just with `ExecStop` and didn't work) after `shutdown.target` and that is wanted by `final.target`.

- `/etc/systemd/system/clear-stick.service`:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Cleans-up interview sticker

  DefaultDependencies=no
  Before=final.target umount.target
  After=shutdown.target

  [Service]
  Type=oneshot
  ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/clear_interview_stick.sh
  RemainAfterExit=true

  [Install]
  WantedBy=final.target
  ```

It also helped seeing how the [casper-rw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent) overlay did it (I mean: looking at [the actual `/etc/systemd/system/final.target.wants/casper.service` file](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/tree/debian/casper.service)) and how it uses `ExecStart`, makes it run after `umount` (although I wanted my service run *before* umount)... things like that.

Also, in one of my <sub>many</sub> tests I removed the line `RequiresMountsFor=/media/overlay/` It might still be ok (I didn't try all the possible permutations), but since at the time that `mount /media/overlay` was being  done through `/etc/rc.local`, ([mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) takes over the `/etc/fstab`), and what I did works without it, I kept it out.

In the previous paragraph, I mention *"but since **at the time** that `mount`..."* That's because just in case SystemD was not *"seeing"* a mount that wasn't listed in the `/etc/fstab` but created through `rc.local`, I also created a `.mount` unit file as [explained here](https://oguya.ch/posts/2015-09-01-systemd-mount-partition/), to try having SystemD know about it. Plus it felt cleaner to me.

This is how:

- `/etc/systemd/system/media-overlay.mount`:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Mount Overlay in /media/

  [Mount]
  What=/dev/disk/by-label/casper-rw
  Where=/media/overlay
  Type=ext4
  Options=defaults

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```

That didn't help with the erasing. I'm **guessing** maybe???? (big guess, big maybe) that's because I was still using *Exec**Stop***? I dunno, really. Nonetheless, that `.mount` file did succeeded in creating the `mount`, so I kept it.

I'm sure a cleaner and more reliable `.service` could be written, but since each *test* took me more than half an hour because I needed to rebuild the bootable USB stick, I decided leaving it like this. (If it compiles, it ships, right?)

It is worth noting that the [`list-dependencies`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945688/how-to-list-all-services-that-start-after-certain-service-in-systemd) command (as in `systemctl list-dependencies --after final.target`) was also really helpful to see what was going on.

Comment: Looks good to me :-)